# Subset function in R works on one column but not on the other

Tags: r

I am trying to get some NBA data. However, I can't seem to be able to select a subset of my data properly. I tried using the subset function to get only the players with more than 10 games but it doesn't work for some reason. It subset works when I use a different column and I don't know why. Here's my code

```
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
require("httr")
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)
require('jsonlite')
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
require(dplyr)


params = list(AheadBehind="Ahead or Behind", ClutchTime="Last 5 Minutes",
               College="", Conference="", Country="",DateFrom="", DateTo="", 
               Division="", DraftPick="", DraftYear="", GameScope="", 
               GameSegment="", Height="", LastNGames= "0", LeagueID="00",
               Location="", MeasureType="Base", Month="0", OpponentTeamID="0",
               Outcome="", PORound="0", PaceAdjust="N", PerMode="PerGame",
               Period="0", PlayerExperience="", PlayerPosition="", 
               PlusMinus= "N", PointDiff="5", Rank="N", Season="2020-21",
               SeasonSegment="",SeasonType="Regular Season", ShotClockRange="", 
               StarterBench="", TeamID="0", VsConference="", VsDivision="", 
               Weight="" )

request_headers = c('Accept'='application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Accept-Encoding'='gzip, deflate, br',
                    'Accept-Language'="en-US,en;q=0.9",
                    'Connection'='keep-alive',
                    'Host'='stats.nba.com',
                    'Origin'='https://www.nba.com',
                    'Referer'='https://www.nba.com/',
                    'Sec-Fetch-Dest'='empty',
                    'Sec-Fetch-Mode'='cors',
                    'Sec-Fetch-Site'='same-site',
                    'User-Agent'='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36',
                    'x-nba-stats-origin'='stats',
                    'x-nba-stats-token'='true')


base <- 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/'
endpoint_players_clutch <- 'leaguedashplayerclutch'
call <- paste(base, endpoint_players_clutch, sep = '')
res <- httr::GET(call, httr::add_headers(.headers=request_headers), query=params)
json_resp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res, "text"))

df <- data.frame(json_resp$resultSets$rowSet[1])
colnames(df) <- json_resp[["resultSets"]][["headers"]][[1]]

df2 <- select(df, PLAYER_NAME, GP, PLUS_MINUS)

df3 <- subset(df2, GP > 10)

# The line below works, but not the one above 
# df3 <- subset(df2, PLUS_MINUS > 0)
```

Any solution would help, but it would help if the solution uses the subset function so that I know what I did wrong. Thanks

Comment: `GP` is character not numeric. It's subsetting all the numbers after `10` in the alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show what should have been done:

```
 df2 <- select(df, PLAYER_NAME, GP, PLUS_MINUS)
 
 str(df2)       # notice that GP displays like  'numeric' but is really 'factor'
#--------------
'data.frame':   382 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ PLAYER_NAME: Factor w/ 382 levels "Aaron Gordon",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ GP         : Factor w/ 23 levels "1","10","11",..: 22 22 12 12 6 1 21 1 2 12 ...
 $ PLUS_MINUS : Factor w/ 89 levels "-0.1","-0.2",..: 53 63 33 29 3 39 14 86 78 10 ...
#-----------------------
 df2$GP <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$GP))  #convert factor to numeric
 df3 <- subset(df2, GP > 10)
 str(df3)
#----------------------
'data.frame':   157 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ PLAYER_NAME: Factor w/ 382 levels "Aaron Gordon",..: 5 13 14 16 17 21 23 29 31 32 ...
 $ GP         : num  14 18 16 11 14 18 18 13 17 12 ...
 $ PLUS_MINUS : Factor w/ 89 levels "-0.1","-0.2",..: 3 5 48 76 33 11 66 43 10 3 ...
#----------
```

If this had been the result of a `read.table` or other `read.*` operation then depending on your version of R the GP column might have been either factor as it was for me in my 3.6.2 session or character as it might have been for anyone using an up-to-date version. The default for stringsAsFactors was changed in the transition to version 4 and above. When it is a factor, the GP column would first needs to be converted to character before it can be converted to numeric. In your case it might be that jsonlite has not yet made the same decision about assuming columns that can be numeric *should* be numeric.

If you are running R 4.0+ or above, you don't need the `as.character` inside the `as.numeric`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot, including the information regarding the version of R.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you're working with, and since you have a lot of variables (66), you could use the `type.convert` helper function to convert the `df` data object variables to logical, integer, numeric, character, factor, etc. as appropriate. This would be a good initial step to making sure the variable's in the initial data frame `df` are of the appropriate type.

For example:

`df <- type.convert(data.frame(json_resp$resultSets$rowSet[1]))`